# Adding Angular-Google-Maps to Mean.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, angular-google-maps

I am having an issue trying to add a module (angular-google-maps) to Mean.js

I ran:

```
bower install angular-google-maps --save
```

Then added 'google-maps' to public/config.js in the applicationModuleVendorDependencies array:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'google-maps'];
```

But when I try to run (using grunt) I get an error:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'google-maps' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Is there some other step I need to do? On https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use it says angular-google-maps depends on Lodash, do I have to add this in the module vendor dependencies also?

Comment: Added this code manually to app\views\layout.server.view.html and it works, just won't add automatically `<script type="text/javascript" src='lib/lodash/dist/lodash.underscore.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular-google-maps does not include the google-maps js api. You need to add it manually to your js-libs in config/env/all.js. This is also the place where you can add the lodash and angular-google-maps js files:

```
assets: {
    lib: {
        js: [
            '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',
            'public/lib/lodash/dist/lodash.underscore.js',
            'public/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know about that file, I thought it was automatically scraping the bower packages and adding them somehow!